# Linux server sync to an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: rsync, amazon-s3, s3fs, s3cmd

I am looking for a stable solution to replace a classic server backup to another server using `rsync`.
I have to sync a whole filesystem (more than 1Tb) to Amazon S3.

Where am I?

Solution 1:
I mapped the S3 bucket to a mounting point in the system using `s3fs`.
System gets unstable and traffic is really slow. This is no way a solution.

Solution 2:
Using `s3cmd sync` command. Everything goes smooth at good speeds (at least for less than 2Gb folders).
The problem comes when I try to sync all the filesystem on the server (with some exclusions). The process just hangs.

Any hints?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Cheap and good storage place. As long as you don't need all your files restored (that's the moment it gets expensive). Seems like a good idea, but, technically, I have this problem. The backup is daily and must be incremental (this is why I am looking for rsync behavior).

Comment: Look at the duplicity backup app, which has great  S3 support.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So far, so good. Works alright on folders under 1Gb. I will test tomorrow the heavy ones.

Comment: Duplicity worked fine, but because all the packing and archiving and everything that defines it as a good tool, it becomes really slow and I cannot use it to keep 2T synced to S3. Still, I recommend it for smaller amounts of data to be synced.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad way to do backups. You should be separating your OS configuration from your valuable data. None of your permissions will be transferred, which in the Linux world are a necessity if you're planning on restoring backups (which you should be - backups without verified restorations are pointless).

Firstly, you can synchronise your valuable instance data (e.g. `/var/www`) to S3 using `s3cmd sync` as you've stated.

Secondly, using a configuration management utility such as Puppet or Chef, you can spin up a new instance of your OS with minimal effort, ensuring a fresh and reliable set of configurations.

There's no details of your underlying architecture in your question (EC2? VMware? KVM? Xen? Physical hardware?) so I can't recommend any specific tools (i.e. architecture-specific snapshotting). If you're running on a virtual platform (e.g. EC2, VMware, KVM) you should be using that platform's snapshotting architecture.

Comment: /var/www would be 99,9% of the whole data we keep. And because there is one major project, file permissions are not really the problem. System is a CentOS on 64b on a dedicated server.

Comment: `s3cmd sync --delete-removed /var/ s3://bucket/var/` is what I am trying to fix. Stays like this for hours.